# Error: system file has been modified since precompiled header was built

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I just downloaded the final version of xcode 6 and to compile a project that I was working with the beta, now generates the following error simulator apparently, someone can help me with this.

```
fatal error: file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/
Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk/usr/include/sysexits.h' has been modified since the 
precompiled header '/Users/Lycros/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/NZL05J5PKZ6B/
UIKit-301UUGFC4BK8R.pcm' was built
```

he error occurs when I try to compile on the simulator iphone 5s, 6, 6 plus and both resizables.
works in another than iphone 5, 4 etc. . .

Comment: Did you try a ***Clean All*** so the precompiled header gets rebuilt?

Comment: I try product -> clean and product -> clean buil folder but dont work

Comment: How about `Cmd + Opt + Shft + K`?

Comment: yes that way and dont work, the error occurs only with the last iphone simulator 5s,6,6 plus

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Quit Xcode and remove everything in the module cache located here:

`~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache`

The cache that was built with a previous version of Xcode is invalid for this version of Xcode and SDK, and that is causing your error.

Comment: I would have had no idea how to fix this. Thank you!

Comment: What a stupid and time wasting problem this is! For me, it happened right out of the blue. Thanks very much!

Comment: Thanks. We all still would be in primitive age of coding fixing these timewasting issues if there was no SO. Kudos to SO and community.Thanks

Comment: silly issue! thank you very much, outstanding answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you change your deployment target to 8.0, you can get it to run on iPhone 6 simulator.

Mine wasn't working either, I updated deployment target to 8.0, cleaned project, ran on simulator and the build worked fine.

Then I downgraded the deployment target to 7.1, picked 5S 7.1 simulator and it also correctly built and ran.

Comment: Running it on 8.0 actually worked for me when all the other methods I found (deep cleaning, clearing module cache, touching pch files, etc) didn't work. Changing it back to 7.1 didn't though, but who cares, I've got a build to hand over to Facebook. 

In Xcode itself, surprisingly changing a device (like 5 to 5S) actually worked for me (with the same deployment target). Not sure why, that of course did not solve the problem.