# Header File Changed mistakenly and stuck on running on Simulator in Xcode 6.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I Just have add space mistakenly and close my project now I am stuck on this following issue.

```
fatal error: file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSDate.h' has been modified since the precompiled header '/Volumes/Project/User/Data/Projects/Spender/Code/Git/MyProject/DerivedData/SPENDER/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/MyProject-Prefix-fhkddqkqywndkaajlfbnfgoftvif/MyProject-Prefix.pch.pch' was built
```

I googled and try every thing to delete Dervied folder, .PCM file and also clean, like also shown in this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463179/how-to-fix-pch-error).
So Kindly give my any idea how to fix this issue, I am on Xcode 6.0.
Looking for those who were victim of this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Delete Xcode and reinstall it. That's probably the easiest way to restore your iOS 8.0 SDK.

Answer (score 1):

This type of error is usually fixed by cleaning the `DerivedData` folder, cleaning (CMD+K) the project and building (CMD+B). Restarting Xcode may also help.

Your original post isn't clear. Did you see those responses without attempting them, or did you attempt those solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same problem.  Delete the

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache directory
```

and restart Xcode.

(Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951998/error-system-file-has-been-modified-since-precompiled-header-was-built) excellent answer;  adding here for googlers)